# Microsoft Report error in C#

Tags: .net, reporting-services, report, c#-2.0

I am using a Microsoft report to show a report.
It works fine in my PC. But when it is put on a client PC (Which has .NEt 2.0 platform)
it gives following error when loading the form from reportviewer.

Error Message:

An error occurred during local report processing.

Error Hash Code:

36482533

Error Source:

Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms

Stack Trace:

at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Report.SetParameters(ReportParameter parameter)
   at HCH.Patient.rptViewer.rptViewer_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

I am passing few parameters to the report from the report viewer. And they do match in name. Like I said, this works in my PC.And this project is for platform .NET 2.0.

Kindly help me if you have clue. Please don't hesitate to query me if anything is not clear in the question. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the report viewer software on the client PC or create an installer that does. Report Viewer is not part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Hi.. Yes, I have installed it from the following link.   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21916  But still it is the same. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You must **include** those **DLLs** in your Application **Deployment**

- Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization
- Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel

You will find them in : 
 **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\**

Then you will need to run **ReportViewer.exe** on your Machine .

You will find it in : 
**C:\Program Files\MicrosoftSDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ReportViewer\**

Then when you deploy your Application select from prerequisites : **Microsoft visual studio 2010 report viewer** or **the Compatible version with your Project**